# different collections of child elements

Tags: schema, xsd

is it  possible to create a schema where the children of an element would be partialy in a sequence and partiali not? something like this:

```
<xs:element name="rootElement">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:all>
   <xs:element name="value1" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="value2" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:all>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="value3" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="value4" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post some more information. The answer is 'yes' but your question is too vague to say more. If you could post some XML it would help.

Comment: ok I want to validate an xml which looks somehow like this: 
<house>
 <ownerName>aaa</ownerName>
 <ownerLastName>bbb</ownerLastName>
 <rooms>
  <room1>kitchen</room1>
  <room2>living room</room2>
  <room3></room3>
  <room4></room4>
  <room5></room5>
 </rooms>
</house>

The child elements of rooms will always apper in that order, but the name and last name will show up in any order. So I wanted to list the child elements of rooms in a sequence and the name elements in an all tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think I understand you know. Your XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<house> 
    <ownerName>aaa</ownerName>
    <ownerLastName>bbb</ownerLastName>
    <rooms>
        <room1>kitchen</room1>
        <room2>living room</room2>
        <room3></room3>
        <room4></room4> 
        <room5></room5>
    </rooms>
</house>
```

You want the `ownerName` and `ownerLastName` elements to occur in any order although they must both be present. It's not clear from your description it the position of the `rooms` element is important. I have assumed it is. It's import that the child elements of `rooms` remain in order.

Splitting this up, we can define a `complexType` for rooms (so the model is complete)

```
<xs:complexType name="RoomType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="RoomsType">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="room1" type="RoomType"/>
            <xs:element name="room2" type="RoomType"/>
            <xs:element name="room3" type="RoomType"/>
            <xs:element name="room4" type="RoomType"/>
            <xs:element name="room5" type="RoomType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This gives us the sequence of rooms in order.

There are quite a few limitations on the use of `xs:all` so I've avoided it here (you can't use in a sequence, for example). In order to allow the owner names to occur in any order, I've used a choice of two sequences. The choice is embedded in another sequence to ensure that the `rooms` element comes last.

```
<xs:complexType name="HouseType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ownerName"/>
                <xs:element ref="ownerLastName"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ownerLastName"/>
                <xs:element ref="ownerName"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="rooms" type="HouseType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="house" type="HouseType"/>
```

Now, if you actually don't care about the order or `ownerLastName`, `ownerName` *and* `house` then you can use `xs:all` without a problem:

```
<xs:complexType name="HouseType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="ownerName"/>
        <xs:element ref="ownerLastName"/>
        <xs:element name="rooms" type="HouseType"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

which requires that you have all three elements present in any order.

Comment: very well explained! Tahnk you so much for the help. Best regards, Jarek